# load page with inactive scrollbar

Tags: html, browser

I have a page that scrolls through images, some taller than the others. When a tall image loads it auto-creates a scrollbar in the browser window, causing a width jerk. Is there a way to load a scroll bar regardless of if it is needed, and when a tall image apears it activates itself accordingly, then deactivates its self accordingly when the image changes to a shorter image?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
div {
  overflow: scroll;
}
```

ought to do it. That will put up scrollbars whether or not they are called for. You can get fancier by doing

```
div {
  overflow-x: scroll;
}
```

if you just want horizontal scrollbars or

```
div {
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

if you just want vertical scrollbars. From your question it sounds like you are interested in the latter solution.

Comment: gracious, This happened to work over the div css:
body {
  overflow: scroll;
}

Answer (score 0):

Make a container div for the images, then make its `height:110%;` or any height > 100%.